# Vue Component that Can Override What Child Renders Dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on a component (InfoCard) that should be able to render any number of fields passed into it with a 'fields' prop, as an array of json objects with a name, value, and some styling options. For certain fields, I want to be able to override what component is used to render, but do it from the parent (Table) rather than inside the InfoCard component, as it should be generic. My first thought was to use a `<component :is='field.component'></component>`, where it will render as plaintext if `field.component` is not defined, but to my understand it will be difficult to pass in any potential children necessary for the `<component/>`. My second thought is to use named slots from within the parent, but I don't think this is possible either in a good way. I'll show my current code.

In my example, I want to be able to detect if the field being rendered is 'status', and if it is, use a different rendering mechanism than `displayValue(attribute)`, without hardcoding it inside InfoCard; I want the parent to be able to override this rendering conditionally. Is there a way to do this in Vue? Thanks

From Table, where data.records is an array of JSON objects:

```html
        <info-card
          v-for="(record,index) in data.records"
          :key="index"
          :fields="record"
        >
          <div v-for="key in Object.keys(record)" :key="key">
            <template v-if="field.name=='status'" v-slot:[`${field.name}_value`]>
              <p> Field is status !</p>
            </template>
          </div>
        </info-card>
```

From InfoCard:

```html
<template>
       <el-col
          :lg="3"
          :md="3"
          :sm="3"
          :xs="3"
          v-for="(attribute, index) in fields"
          :key="index"
          class="attribute"
        >
          <div
            @click="$emit('fieldClicked', attribute)"
          >
            <el-row 
              :class="`mid-gray f6 clipped fw5-ns m-b-10 ${attribute.nameClasses}`" 
              :title="displayName(attribute)"
              :style="attribute.nameStyle?attribute.nameStyle:''"
            >
              <slot
                v-if="Object.keys($scopedSlots).includes(`${attribute.name}_name`)"
                :name="$scopedSlots[`${attribute.name}_name`]"
              >
              </slot>
              <div v-else>
                {{ displayName(attribute) }}
              </div>
            </el-row>
            <el-row
              :class="`mid-gray f6 clipped fw5-ns m-b-10 ${attribute.valueClasses}`"
              :title="displayValue(attribute)"
              :style="attribute.valueStyle?attribute.valueStyle:''"
            >
              <slot
                v-if="Object.keys($scopedSlots).includes(`${attribute.name}_value`)"
                :name="$scopedSlots[`${attribute.name}_value`]"
              >
              </slot>
              <div v-else>
                {{ displayValue(attribute) }}
              </div>
            </el-row>
          </div>
        </el-col>
</template>
```

Comment: It depends entirely on you to choose between the 2 available methods - providing your content inside the parent (by using the corresponding slot/s from child) or alternating between different children (by using `<component :is>`). If you need a totally different look between the 2 variants - `<component>` would be the right choice. If you only need to change some parts of the look - then you can get away with `slots` only.

Comment: In the `<component>` case, is there any way to pass child content for that component? Perhaps I'm thinking of this too much from a react perspective - there it would be more trivial to just pass the entire element needed to render in the child as a prop, but it seems there is no true equivalent in Vue?

Comment: It is a bad practice to tell the child **how** to render - this knowledge is already incapsulated into your child. A good practice is to tell your child **what** to render. You're free to combine both methods - using `<component>` and then providing content into its slot(s). If the particular `:is` instance does not have the slot you are feeding content into - this slot will be ignored. But in my opinion, without any insight into your use case, it looks like you're trying to make your life more complicated that it could be.